# Can Npgsql 3.1 automatically convert between PostgreSQL enums and text, like Npgsql 2.2 did?

Tags: npgsql

I'm upgrading an application from Npgsql 2.2 to Npgsql 3.1. It uses many enums and I have many errors like this:

```
Npgsql.PostgresException : 42804: column "my_column" is of type my_enum but expression is of type text
```

This seems to happen even with a simple INSERT, like this

`INSERT INTO my_table (col1, col2, col3, ...)
SELECT $1, $2, $3, ...
RETURNING 1 AS _row_affected`

Each column value is added as a parameter using `NpgsqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(name, value)` (without specifying the type). The .NET type of the value is a `string` in this case.

In Npgsql 2.2 this worked, because it transparently converted text to Postgres enums and vice-versa. Is there a way to get the same behaviour in 3.1? I know that it handles enums natively now, which can be useful, but it would really *really* simplify the upgrade if I could get the enums working as text again!

Comment: Can you please post some code to show what exactly you're trying to achieve? Npgsql 3.1 does allow you to transparently read enums as strings but there may be something unhandled...

Comment: I'm actually trying to insert in this case, not read. I've added a very simplified version. The real code is far more complicated, so there might be more going on that I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating the parameter, try settings its NpgsqlDbType to Unknown, this should make PostgreSQL transparently convert the text value into an enum.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work for enums. I ran into the same error with a domain (`DOMAIN time_type AS time without time zone`) and `Unknown` didn't help for that. When I tried to specify the type as `Time` it seemed to expect a TimeSpan. Any easy way to get Postgres to convert my time strings (like "12:34") to the right type?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... Setting `NpgsqlDbType.Unknown` should make it possible to send a textual representation for any type as long as PostgreSQL can infer that type from the query context. Maybe open another question with the full details...